# High voltage battery charging with low voltage charger?

Tags: battery-charging, circuit-design

I have two 3.7V batteries to be used serially for my device. Is there any way to charge these batteries with 3.7V charger? Or do someone show me a circuit having a button which when pressed connects the two batteries serially which then can be used by the device. And when the switch is not pressed connects the two batteries in parallel which then can be charged with 3.7V charger connected in parallel to the two batteries.

Comment: What type of charging regime do the batteries require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adafruit posted an [article](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-cell-lipo-charging/overview) on this.  You'll need a 3PDT switch, unfortunately, but it's safe and relatively simple.

[image: Charging 'schematic']

Comment: Thanks bro. Actually I had myself designed such circuit with 3pdt but was unsure about the safety.